# How to return multiple parameters using select_tag in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, drop-down-menu

```
<% select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
  [["Detail1", 1], ["Detail2", 2], ["Detail3", 3], ["Detail4", 4], ["Detail5", 5], ["Detail6", 6], ["Detail7", 7]]))%>
<% submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
```

I have the above select menu. This would return report_id parameter based on the value selected by the user. Now, I need another parameter named format to be set as :xlsx if report_id is 1 or 2 and format should be set to :pdf if report_id > 2. How can I achieve this? Please help!

I tried something like this but this does not work:

```
<% select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
  [["Detail1", 1], ["Detail2", 2], ["Detail3", 3], ["Detail4", 4], ["Detail5", 5], ["Detail6", 6], ["Detail7", 7]]))%>


<% if report_id < 3 %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :xlsx %>
<% elsif report_id >=3 %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag :format, :pdf %>
<% end %>


<% submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
```

I get this error with the above code:

[image: format parameter error]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here you can do two things.**

- You can write if condition in your controller once the action is trigger

  `if params[:report_id] >= 3
      format = 'pdf'
     else
      format = 'xlsx'
     end`
- OR if you want send from form itself then you need to write jquery onchange event

  `<% select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
  [["Detail1", 1], ["Detail2", 2], ["Detail3", 3], ["Detail4", 4], ["Detail5", 5], ["Detail6", 6], ["Detail7", 7]])) id: "something"%>`
- Jquery

  `$('#something').on('change', function() {
   if(this.value >= 3) {
     $('#hidden_value').val('pdf')
   } else {
     $('#hidden_value').val('xlsx');
   }
   })`
- hidden field
  `<% hidden_field_tag :format , id: "hidden_value" %>`

Answer (score 1):

You can't access value of `report_id` untill unless you submit it to server. You can use JS/jquery to update `format` parameter value whenever the select_tag value changes

```
<% select_tag(:report_id, options_for_select(
  [["Detail1", 1], ["Detail2", 2], ["Detail3", 3], ["Detail4", 4], ["Detail5", 5], ["Detail6", 6], ["Detail7", 7]]), id: "report_id")%>
<%= hidden_field_tag :format, :xlsx, id: "format_param" %>
<% submit_tag("Generate Report") %>
```

JS to assign format params value whenever select_tag value changes

```
$("#report_id").change(function(){
  var report_val = $("#report_id").val();
  if(report_val < 3)
    $('#format_param').val("xlsx")
  else
     $('#format_param').val("pdf")
})
```

Comment: thanks much for your reply! Just a quick question please? the javascript code that you showed - can I place that in a separate javascript file in assets/javascripts folder? If I call this as "generate_report.js", should I register this js somewhere (say application.js)? My question is, how will the application know it has to use this js file?

I apologise for the silly question; I am a newbie of sorts for rails!

Comment: Yes, you have to place it in assets/javascripts directory, you don't need to import or register in application.js if application.js contains this line` //= require_tree .` if this line is not present then register `generate_reports.js` file in application.js like this `//= require generate_report`

Comment: I tried using the exact same js snippet that you had shared. But the format param seems to be always pdf no mater what value I choose. :(

Comment: Sorry thats my bad, Just updated the Js snipet please use this one now

Comment: I skipped passing the format parameter and passed only the report_id parameter. And I set the report format in the controller solely based on the report_id. That worked for me. (I was not able to pass 2 parameters though; I kept getting one error or the other that way).

Talha,  @user3678149  - Thank you very much for your inputs!!